# How can I label conversations in Gmail using only the keyboard?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't like using the mouse. It's slower than knowing keyboard shortcuts really well and using them.

I want to label conversations in my Gmail inbox using only the keyboard.

Couldn't find anything useful in the Gmail keyboard shortcut list.

Is there any way to do it? Even customizing it myself with something like Greasemonkey?

Comment: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6594

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To label the currently open mail, press <kbd>L</kbd> and start typing the label. Matching labels will appear as you type, so you can just navigate to the one you want (using arrow keys) and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

To label AND archive the mail at the same time, press <kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>L</kbd> and follow the same procedure.

In the mail list view, use <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> to move up and down the list (the tiny arrow to the left of each item will move), press <kbd>X</kbd> to select one or more mails and then use <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>V</kbd> to add labels.

Answer (score 2):

By default, only basic keyboard shortcuts are enabled in Gmail. You have to enable the additional keyboard shortcuts in settings. You can press '?' in Gmail to see a popup list of all keyboard shortcuts and which are currently enabled or disabled. You can also enable & disable the additional shortcuts in the popup that appears.

See more detail here: [Keyboard shortcuts for Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en).